# Some very few images are rendered with inverted colors by Magento

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.6, debugging

We have the problem, that one image in the catalog is shown negatively in Magento below the gallery.

I tried to reproduce with `n98-magerun2 dev:console`

```
$i = $di->create('\Magento\Framework\Image',
  ['fileName' => 'original.jpg']);
$i->open();
$i->resize(90,90);
$i->save('small-repro.jpg');
```

Which I cant.

While I can reproduce it by

```
rm product/cache/.... $ rm small.jpg
```

and reloading the category page -> it's shown wrong again.

The image also shoes like this when downloading or showing in different browsers, so it seems to be a problem within the server / Magento.

1. Did anybody see this before?
2. How can I dig deeper into it?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Do you have the same problem? Actually I did not find a real solution but deleted that particular image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be down to the image being in the CMYK colour space, Imagick can have issues when working with these images as it is unable to convert to RGB properly.

You can either upload a preconverted image, or trying patching in a way for Magento to deal with this issue with the use of `setImageColourSpace` and a nice little if around `$image->getImageColorspace() == Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK` to set the correct ICC profile.

Comment: One thing remains strange: Why can I not reproduce it via the simple n98-magerun commands

Comment: in which file I do this change?